# Difference between `*&p` vs `&*p`?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int a=10;
int *p=&a;
```

now looking at `&*p` we first look at `*p` which is `10` and then at `&10`
which is the address of `10` or the address of `a`

In the case of `*&p` we first look at the address of `p` and then at the value in this address which is `10`

But I understand that both `*&p` vs `&*p` are the same, why?

Comment: Note: If `p` is not a pointer, `&*p` will not compile, yet `*&p` will.

Comment: @chux if `p` is not a pointer or will not be converted to one, then...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala True, `p` could be an array.

Comment: ... or a function ;)

Answer (score 5):

Lets draw your variables:

```
+---+     +---+
| p | --> | a |
+---+     +---+
```

That is, `p` is pointing to `a`.

Now if you do `&*p` then you first dereference `p` to get `a`, then you get the address of `a`, which leaves you with a pointer to `a`.

If we take `*&p` then you get the address of `p` to get a pointer to `p`, then you dereference that pointer to get `p`. Which is a pointer to `a`.

So while the expressions do different things, the end result is the same: A pointer to `a`.

And a descent compiler would probably just do nothing at all, since the dereference operator `*` and address-of operator `&` together will always cancel each other out, no matter in which order they are.

Comment: 6.5.3.2p3 states that `&*` cancels out, but doesn't say anything about `*&`.

Comment: What happens if `p` is concurrently modified by another thread? I take it that `&*` is undefined behavior then, but `*&` is not, at least not intrinsically (i.e you could say `&*&`, put a `&` in front of everything to prevent a read).

Answer (score 2):

Considering below example

```
int a=10;
int *p=&a;
```

this

```
*&p
```

means here both `*` and `&` gets nullified and it result in `p` which is nothing but `&a`.

And this

```
&*p
```

means first dereference `p` which gives `a` and then reference `&` i.e address of `a` which is nothing but `p`, same as the first case.

Answer (score 1):

By the [clockwise / spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html):

For `*&p`:

```
             +-----+
             | +-+ |
             | ^ | |
           * & p ; |
           ^ ^   | |
           | +---+ |
           +-------+
```

- We first take the address of `p`, which is at this point the address of the address of `a`.
- Then we dereference that, which gives the address of `a`.

For `&*p`:

```
             +-----+
             | +-+ |
             | ^ | |
           & * p ; |
           ^ ^   | |
           | +---+ |
           +-------+
```

- We first dereference `p`, which gives us `a`.
- We then take the address of that, which gives us the address of `a`, just like before.

Comment: Not the clockwise spiral rule; that's for types. These are just 2 unary operators that have the same [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), and are evaluated right-to-left. (`&*p` -> `(&(*(p)))`)

Answer (score 0):

In this context, `&` takes the address (i.e., informally "adds `*`" to the type of the expression). Meanwhile `*` dereferences a pointer (i.e., "removes a `*`" from the type of the expression). Therefore:

```
int *p = …;
p; // int *
*p; // int
&*p; // int *
&p; // int **
*&p; // int *
```

So, yes, in this context the result is the same: a pointer to `int`, because the `&` and the `*` cancel out. However, this is also why the combinations are pointless: the result is the same as `p` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

`*&p` == `*(&p)`. `&p` is an pointer to the pointer or int. `*(&p)` is a value to which pointer of pointer points, which is value of `p`. To continue, `**&p` will print '10'.

`&*p` == `&(*p)` where `*p` is the value at which the pointer points (value of `a`). Now `&` is an address of `a`, which is `p` again. And to go further, `*&*p` will print value of `a` (10).