# What is int *(&) declaration in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I came across this piece of code

```
int a = 10;    ---> i)
int *p = &a;   ---> ii)
int *(&q) = p; ---> iii)
```

Here in statement `iii)`,  `q` seems to look like a pointer having the same value as `p`(after resolving)([reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53935936/10454814)). However, while we are still defining, `&q` tries to get the address of q which hasn't yet been created. So, how do you logically explain this in pointer terms? Any resources to explain this is also appreciated.

NOTE: I did compile and run the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/xYfTo8ETT), `q` points to `a`.

Comment: If the question is about C++, then don't tag it with C.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The above code compiles both in c and c++ So added both tags.

Comment: it also compiles in other differernt languages, but thats not relevant when the quesiton is about C++

Comment: [No, it doesn't](https://ideone.com/UQfp8x)

Comment: It's a reference of the `p` pointer (as any reference variable). What in particular don't you understand?

Comment: Also this does _not_ compile in C because `int *(&q)` is gibberish there.

Comment: its a pointer to an int reference

Comment: @EugeneSh. My bad, the stackoverflow links I attached to explain, used C, didn't crosscheck

Comment: *NOTE: I did compile and run the code, `q` points to `a`.*  Yes, but moreso `q` is an **alias** (i.e., a reference) that is bound to `p`, and because `p` points to `a`, `p`'s alias `q` also points to `a`.  Both `p` and its alias `q` are `int*`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you got confused by the brackets, lets remove them:

```
int *& q = p;
```

Maybe you got confused by combination of `*` and `&` to form a reference to pointer, so lets try some obfuscation:

```
using T = int*;  // T is alias for pointer to int
T& q = p;
```

`T& q = p;` declares `q` to be a reference to a `T` and initializes that reference with `p`.

Note that C does not have references as C++ has them.

Answer (score 1):

`int *(&q)` declares a reference to a pointer. The parenthesis achieves nothing and it could as well be written as `int *&q`. It's a rather pointless (pun intended) way of creating a name alias of a pointer. Pretty much the same thing as

```
int a;
int& ref = a;
```

But instead `*&` creates a reference to the pointer itself, rather than at to the data it points at.

Normally one doesn't mix references and pointers in the same context, or at least I can't come up with a sane use-case for this, but it's valid syntax.

Comment: fwiw, writing trees is a hot topic on SO where often a `Node* head` is passed to functions where a `Node*& head` would be required. Though, I don't remember to have seen it in real

Comment: I've used a reference to pointers to process `main(int argc, char **argv`) arguments and adjust them automatically. Declaration is `void foo(int& argc,, char**&argv)`